# How to get certain values from an output

Tags: r

I have a code (source for the code is in the link below) that  creates the following output:

```
df <- read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs     
                        0       21         7  
                        0        8         4  
                        1        2         5 
                        1        2         4 
                        0        8         3 
                        1        1         12  
                        1       7          10 
                        1        1         9 ",header = TRUE)
myform <-NULL
myform <- target~1
dd<-NULL
for ( i in c('birds', 'wolfs')) { 

    myform <- update(myform,  as.formula(paste('~ birds +', i)))
    glm<-glm(myform,data=dat)
    dat$glm_predict_response <- ifelse(predict(glm,newdata=dat,   type="response")>.5, 1, 0)
    sum1<- sum(dat$glm_predict_response>0 & dat$target>0)
    sum2<- sum(dat$glm_predict_response<1 & dat$target<1)
    accuracy<- (sum1+sum2)/length(dat$glm_predict_response)
    print(myform)
    print(accuracy)

}
```

## Output:

```
target ~ birds
[1] 0.75
target ~ birds + wolfs
[1] 1
```

Is it possible to get only results that are above a certain value? for example in this output only the model formula that preduce the best accuracy value, In this case:

```
target ~ birds + wolfs
[1] 1
```

The source for the code is from link: [How to make an output txt file look better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232745/how-to-make-an-output-txt-file-look-better)

Comment: The first solution that should come to mind is an `if` condition ...

Comment: You could start by saving all your output to a vector or something, that makes selection afterwards a lot easier. Currently you're only printing it, so you only save the last occurence.

Comment: Hello @Roland, How can you use the if function having an output as a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the results in a list like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs     
                        0       21         7  
                        0        8         4  
                        1        2         5 
                        1        2         4 
                        0        8         3 
                        1        1         12  
                        1       7          10 
                        1        1         9 ",header = TRUE)
myform <-NULL
myform <- target~1
dd<-NULL
#I am initiating a list here
mylist <- list()
for ( i in c('birds', 'wolfs')) { 

  myform <- update(myform,  as.formula(paste('~ birds +', i)))
  glm<-glm(myform,data=dat)
  dat$glm_predict_response <- ifelse(predict(glm,newdata=dat,   type="response")>.5, 1, 0)
  sum1<- sum(dat$glm_predict_response>0 & dat$target>0)
  sum2<- sum(dat$glm_predict_response<1 & dat$target<1)
  accuracy<- (sum1+sum2)/length(dat$glm_predict_response)
  #I am adding each accuracy to the list
  #the name of each element of the list will be the formula(this is what deparse does here)
  #just as a side note: deparse does not work with very big formulas
  #you should use: Reduce(paste, deparse(myform))
  mylist[[deparse(myform)]] <- accuracy 

}
```

The result will be:

```
mylist
$`target ~ birds`
[1] 0.75

$`target ~ birds + wolfs`
[1] 1
```

Now since you have all of the results here, you could `sink` everything to a text file (if you want) using:

```
sink('myfile.txt')
print(mylist)
sink()
```

And then you could only output the best model on screen using:

```
#which.max chooses the max accuracy here
mylist[which.max(unlist(mylist))]
$`target ~ birds + wolfs`
[1] 1
```

Or just sink the best model to the txt file:

```
sink('myfile.txt')
print(mylist[which.max(unlist(mylist))])
sink()
```

Comment: Thank you @LyzandeR for your time and efforts..It works great.

Comment: Np I am happy to help :)

Comment: Hello @LyzandeR ,A bit late but I have two q's in regard to your solution, It will great if you could answer the: first,if I have more than one KPI for choosing the best model(i.e, accuracy should be maximum and sum1 should be minimum) How can I add it's output to the accuracy KPI?second,If I have several models that have the same KPI values , how can I present all of them and not only the first model that meets the KPI?

Comment: Hi @mql4beginner . If you have a new question please ask it as a new one providing a reproducible example. There should only be one question per post so that other users can benefit from reading an answer that solves a particular task. Would be good if you could add your expected output too, because I have difficulty understanding exactly what you nee. You can post the link here if you want so that I can take a look.

Comment: I posted the question in this link, I hope that it is clear now :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898937/how-to-add-sorting-and-several-conditions-to-group-of-printed-outputs

Comment: Thanks @mql4beginner . I will have a look too.