# How to add sorting and several conditions to group of printed outputs

Tags: r, list, loops

Using the code below (source for the code is in the link below) I would like to change / add two things: the ability to present a best subset based on more than one condition and the ability to determine how to sort the subset list and how many subset to show.

```
    dat <- read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs snakes  cats   mice
                            0       21         7     5       9      74
                            0        8         4     4       2      45
                            1        2         5     15      3      45 
                            1        2         4     14      8      45
                            0        8         3     9       4      30 
                            1        1         12    3       16     2   
                            1       7          10    1       11     45
                            1        1         9     4        9     45",header = TRUE)
    myform <-NULL
    myform <- target~1
    dd<-NULL
    for ( i in c('birds', 'wolfs','snakes','cats','mice')) { 

        myform <- update(myform,  as.formula(paste('~ birds +', i)))
        glm<-glm(myform,data=dat)
        dat$glm_predict_response <- ifelse(predict(glm,newdata=dat,   type="response")>.5, 1, 0)
        sum1<- sum(dat$glm_predict_response>0 & dat$target>0)
        sum2<- sum(dat$glm_predict_response<1 & dat$target<1)
        accuracy<- (sum1+sum2)/length(dat$glm_predict_response)
        print(myform)
        print(accuracy)
       mylist[[deparse(myform)]] <- accuracy  
    }
    #In order to find the subset with the highest accuracy value :
    mylist[which.max(unlist(mylist))]
That's working great:

    target ~ birds
    [1] 0.75
    target ~ birds + wolfs
    [1] 1
    target ~ birds + snakes
    [1] 0.75
    target ~ birds + cats
    [1] 1
    target ~ birds + mice
    [1] 0.875
```

EDIT:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs snakes  cats   mice
                            0       21         7     5       9      74
                            0        8         4     4       2      45
                            1        2         5     15      3      45 
                            1        2         4     14      8      45
                            0        8         3     9       4      30 
                            1        1         12    3       16     2   
                            1       7          10    1       11     45
                            1        1         9     4        9     45",header = TRUE)

myform <-NULL
myform <- target~1
mylist<- list()
dd<-NULL
for ( i in c('birds', 'wolfs','snakes','cats','mice')) { 

    myform <- update(myform,  as.formula(paste('~ birds +', i)))
    glm<-glm(myform,data=dat)
    dat$glm_predict_response <- ifelse(predict(glm,newdata=dat,   type="response")>.5, 1, 0)
    sum1<- sum(dat$glm_predict_response>0 & dat$target>0)
    sum2<- sum(dat$glm_predict_response<1 & dat$target<1)
    accuracy<- (sum1+sum2)/length(dat$glm_predict_response)
    print(myform)
    cat("accuracy",accuracy)
    cat('\n\n')
    cat("sum2",sum2)
    mylist[[deparse(myform)]] <- accuracy 
    mylist[[deparse(myform)]] <- sum2 
}

    #In order to find the subset with the highest accuracy value :
    mylist[which.max(unlist(accuracy))]
    mylist[which.min(unlist(sum2))]
    The output that I got is :
    mylist[which.max(unlist(accuracy))]
    $`target ~ birds`
    [1] 1

    > mylist[which.min(unlist(sum2))]
    $`target ~ birds`
    [1] 1
     # How can I get only one output that will be under the 2 conditions? 
    while my Idea is to get only one list,in this example it should be : 
    $`target ~ birds`
        accuracy = 1 , sum2 = 1
```

But I would like to know how can I tell R to find the max value of and the min value of `sum2`. Also, How can I present the output in a sorted way? say I would like to present the first 3 subsect with highest Accuracy and lowest `sum2` should be presented first? So the desired output should look like this(I didn't include in the calc the value of `sum2` as I don't know how to add this metric yet):

```
target ~ birds + wolfs
        [1] 1
target ~ birds + cats
        [1] 1
target ~ birds + mice
        [1] 0.875
```

link to the earlier code: [How to get certain values from an output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237264/how-to-get-certain-values-from-an-output)

Comment: Well you could create a new list in the same way as `mylist` and store `sum2`. In order to print only the first three sorted values you could do: `sort(unlist(mylist), decreasing=TRUE)[1:3]`. And in the same way `max(unlist(mylist))` will give you the max.

Comment: @LyzandeR, I implemented your suggestion (hopefully right) My idea was to get one list that contains the resuls of the two conditions, can I do it ?

Comment: Sure yeah of course you can do it. You can store anything you like in a list. Create the two individual lists first and then do `list(sum2, mylist)` to combine the two in one

Comment: Thanks,I'll work on it..